# Proving a contour integral is zero

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm asked to show that

$$ \int_0^{2\pi} f(e^{it}) \frac{e^{it} \overline{z}}{1-e^{it} \overline{z}} dt = 0 $$

where $z=re^{i\theta}$ and $r<1$.

My first thought was to use Cauchy's integral formula, since this integral can be easily converted to an integral over the unit circle:

$$ \int_0^{2\pi} f(e^{it}) \frac{e^{it} \overline{z}}{1-e^{it} \overline{z}} dt = \frac{1}{i} \int_{\partial B(0,1)} \frac{f(\xi)\overline{z}}{1-\overline{z}\xi} d\xi = \frac{1}{i} \int_{\partial B(0,1)} \frac{f(\xi)r^2}{z-r^2\xi} d\xi = \frac{1}{i} \int_{\partial B(0,1)} \frac{f(\xi)}{z/r^2-\xi} d\xi $$

But as it turns out, $z/r^2 = \frac{1}{r}e^{i\theta}$ is not in the unit disk, so we can't apply Cauchy's integral formula. The integrand has no singularities on the open unit disk so I'd wager it's analytic since the quotient of analytic functions is analytic. Then, we can apply Cauchy's theorem to conclude the integral is zero. Is this line of reasoning correct?

Comment: is not $r=1$?? right

Comment: I guess $f(z)$ is holomorphic ( analytic ) ??

Comment: could you not use the squeeze theorem, since you just need to show its equal to zero?